# Selecting Dynamic ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<div class="html5-video-player iv-module-created iv-module-loaded endscreen-created paused-mode" tabindex="-1" id="player_uid_960859542_1" data-version="//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl_cdzrt/base.js" aria-label="YouTube Video Player">
```

Is there a way for me to select the above element? The id is randomly generated each time and is the css selector (#player_uid_960859542_1) and xpath (//*[@id="player_uid_960859542_1"]). I've tried using the class but it's a compound name. I tried `By.cssSelector(".html5-video-player.iv-module-created.iv-module-loaded.endscreen-created.paused-mode")` but that also failed.

Comment: You don't need **all** classes to match that element. You want as few as possible in order to uniquely match it on that page. Perhaps 'html5-video-player' is sufficient? If your class names are semantic / meaningful, i.e. not merely stylistic, then it's preferable to match that way than upon a generated / dynamic Id.

Comment: have you tried `By.cssSelector("div[id^=player]")` or is that not unique enough?

Comment: @GregWringle Did you try the cssselector like this  `div[class='html5-video-player iv-module-created iv-module-loaded endscreen-created paused-mode']` ?

Comment: Tried all of these suggestions and they didn't work unfortunately.  I tried different combinations of the class names too.  Does it matter that this div is burred beneath another div?

Comment: I found out it's not visible to the driver. It's hidden behind a #documents tag. Is there anyway to access this?

Comment: Can you check if it is under iFrame? If it is so you will have to switch to iFrame first.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned XPath and CSS path is not working because the value of ID is generated dynamically and both XPath and CSS are designed such that it takes ID value to generate the paths while using firebug. however you can try this XPath :
 `//*[@data-version='//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl_cdzrt/base.js'][@aria-label='YouTube Video Player]` In case if it doesn't work you have an option to find a stable element in the DOM and then have an privilage of moving on parent node, child node or sibling node (watch the video for more detail; links are below).

Earlier I was facing the very similar issue and after a lot of R&D I found many ways to handle it using XPath and CSS selector customization.
I have made a video to get the more insights of it. Watch these two videos:
[Create XPath for dynamic elements](https://goo.gl/NDHao1) and
[Create CSS path for dynamic elements](https://goo.gl/i4hyfb)

I'm sure it will help you out as there are many ways to design path to reach out to this element.